# What exactly does this dpkg command do?

Tags: permissions, chmod, dpkg

I fixed a permissin problem for nagios like discribed [here](http://www.idimmu.net/2009/10/30/Error:-Could-not-stat%28%29-command-file-%27/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd%27!).

The command was:

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add nagios www-data 2710 /var/lib/nagios3/rw
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add nagios nagios 751 /var/lib/nagios3
```

Okay its obvious that it is some sort of permission altering. But where does it take place? Where is it stored? Is it just a chmod modification?

Comment: SmallClanger gave a perfect explanation. This command is usually called in maintainer scripts of Debian/Ubuntu packages to set persistant modes to files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dpkg-statoverride` is the management tool for a database maintained by dpkg that contains owner and mode settings for given file paths.

Invoked as in your question, it will do two things: Set the owenrship/mode for the given files immediately if they exist (`--update`) and store a new entry in the override file (`--add`). The latter ensures that further `dpkg` operations that create or modify the listed files will use the override values rather than those defined by the package.

These overrides are permanent. They typically beats a normal `chmod/chown` since it saves you having to remember to reset the permissions manually when you update or reinstall the package.

Existing overrides can be listed by running `dpkg-statoverride --list`.

Comment: Very good answer. I would add that values are stored in a simple text file located in `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* just do it manually. It is simply a change of permissions. The reason for using dpkg-statoverride is that it will remember it on updates and such.

It's a tool to tell dpkg to use those permissions. You are actually able to set it before installing the package as well.

The --update flag is used when changing permissions through dpkg-statoverride on files that already exists.